# How to populate the data from mysql using php as per bootstrap date range?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I want to populate the data form mysql database as per date range where our input are the date range of bootstrap like Predefined Ranges mention in this link http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex4. Actually I populate the data as per defined date from the mysql database.
In my database I have the field name

```
 pi_date as the date field.
```

My mysql query funtion was

```
public function DateAsperRange($start,$end)
{

    $clause .= " DATE(`pa_date`) BETWEEN '{$start}' AND '{$end}'";

    $sql_A = "SELECT *
                FROM  ". $this->table .""

    $sql_A .= $clause;

    global $db;

    $rowsa = $db->query("SET NAMES UTF8");

    $rowsa = $db->query_num_rows($sql_A);

    return $rowsa;
}
```

My Html input name in date picker was

```
<input type="text" value="" name="daterangepicker_start" class="input-mini active">
<input type="text" value="" name="daterangepicker_end" class="input-mini">
<span>February 24, 2016 - February 24, 2016</span>
```

Comment: As i understood your question is that how can you initialize the datepicker from mysql. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment szenbalu. I exactly I want to display data as per two date range which are input form the user form.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date range value in your required format with using [moments.js](http://momentjs.com/).

I think this JavaScript gives you the correct format what you can use in your MySQL query:
`moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY")`